# JS: call methods of an object inside jquery "click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I have a fundamental misunderstanding of one of my numerous errors. I use jquery.

I have an object defined as:

```
var terms = {};

terms.clear_history = function(a, b)
{ /* DO SOMETHING */ }
```

I can call the `terms.clear_history(1,2)` function in my main js file, no problem. But when I try to call it from the "click" of a `<a/>` element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clearterms', function(){
    terms.clear_history(1, 2);
    });
```

it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'clear_history'

I understand that I don't understand something fundamental here...

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use `terms.clear_history(1, 2);` ? I'd like to answer with a complete explanation but I don't understand in what way you didn't understand.

Comment: yes, I did, actually it's what gice me an error (corrected the post to reflect it). Thx

Comment: Do you really use `this` as a function parameter?

Comment: Ok, do you still have the problem after adding `terms` before `clear_history(1, 2);` ?

Comment: this> kinda weird of me to write it here. corrected too! (damn)

Comment: You have to provide more context information and please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the error. The code as you posted it wouldn't throw such an error.

Comment: And if you do use `this` as a function parameter, please stop!

Comment: What error do you still get after the corrections you made?

Comment: It indeed works in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Baloodubronx/5uAJ2/1/).

Comment: Still have the error in my code... I'm calling the "click" from my main html file and the definition of the methods from an external file.

Comment: Well, there is not much we can do if we/you cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can it be that I create my methods in an external file and the "click" callback in the main html file?

Comment: It *could* be an issue depending how exactly you did it, but it's certainly possible to do this over multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a scope issue. Maybe the `terms` in the global scope the same as the one assigned clear_history given the method.
also, you don't want to name your param as `this` which is a reserved keyword in JS.

try this:

```
window.terms = {};
window.terms.clear_history = function(foo,bar){console.log(foo,bar);};

//then later:
$(document).on('click', '#clearterms', function(){
    window.terms.clear_history(1, 2);
});
```

Comment: still got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clear_history' of undefined